# Copying photos and iTunes libraries from an old to a new Mac

Tags: macos, itunes, photos, music

I learned the hard way that I should not copy
`~/Library/Messages/` from an old mac to a new mac. The usual ability to use `Messages` to write messages then works only when writing to iOS users (the blue bubbles); it fails for Android users (the green bubbles). Writing to either from iOS (rather than from macOS) continues to work as normal.

Rather than experiment with the much larger photos and music folders, I'd rather ask.

Does copying `~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/` and `~/Music/iTunes/` from an old mac to a new mac yield usable photos+music collections?

Comment: Please clarify the context of using Android in this instance. It seems a bit strange you reference it.

Comment: @AndyGriffiths Clarified. Is this better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can copy `.photoslibraries` packages between Macs as long as your go-between is an APFS formatted disk. Presumably it can be done using the Migration tool also, but I can't comment as I've never used it.

Music can also be copied in the same way, ensure that you copy your `.musiclibrary` package completely as well as all the actual music files in Media.

Why these differ is that they can be used in a standalone fashion, as well as under the auspices of various iCloud related processes, whereas your Messages folder in Library would probably be a solely iCloud related database, hence why it gets upset if you try to do anything manually to it.

Bear in mind that if copying Photos or Music libraries between different macOS versions, then the libraries may be automatically upgraded when moving to the higher macOS version, and so would probably not work on the older machine. Be sure to keep good backups.